# Background Image Issues - Set height?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm setting a background image on a page, but for some reason, the image is ONLY showing if I had a height. I don't want to set a fixed height though.

Any thoughts?

```
<div class="thinkBPG content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.thinkBPG.content {
    background: url(./home-blueprint.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I was staring at it for way to long.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore this.

I needed to remove the center center fixed.

I told you it was something silly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the content within that div is floated, so you need to tell the browser you want that div to contain it's floated contents. There are a few ways to handle this...you can float that div, you can put overflow on it, or you can use a clearfix solution.

Simplest way without introducing a lot of new code is to simply take off the height, and then add

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
```